# Crystal reports setting for Language

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a report that I run and comes up with different characters based on the {race} field. For example if {race} = Chinese in the report viewer it translates "Chinese: in Chinese characters and for any other race it does the same.

[image: Example of report]

Is this a setting in Crystal reports that I can change this to. 
Also if i run the report on a different PC with Crystal runs fine. 
What could be the setting that is causing this in Crystal Reports XI

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want the whole report content to be translated in Chinese language if field {race} = Chinese ??

Comment: Actually no I need it in English. I don't know what setting was turned on or modified to cause this. So the whole report should be in English.

Comment: Your report, which was in English, spontaneously changed to Chinese?!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

Click Start > Control Panel.
Double-click Regional and Language Settings.
Change the current language to the one preferred. Click Apply > OK. Restart the OS if necessary.
Restart Crystal Reports designer.
The user interface language has been changed.